# Return, but not write on INSERT Trigger Function with table split (postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

Good day,

I have the following problem:

I maintain a database with a huge table - which contents are split/clustered in daily tables.
To do so, I have a Trigger Function which inserts the data into the correct table

This is my trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."insert_example"()
  RETURNS "pg_catalog"."trigger" AS $BODY$
    DECLARE
        _tabledate text;
        _tablename text;
        _start_date text;
        _end_date text;
        
    BEGIN
        --Takes the current inbound "time" value and determines when midnight is for the given date
        _tabledate  := to_char(NEW."insert_date", 'YYYYMMDD');
        _start_date     := to_char(NEW."insert_date", 'YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00');
        _end_date   := to_char(NEW."insert_date", 'YYYY-MM-DD 23:59:59');
        _tablename  := 'zz_example_'||_tabledate;

        -- Check if the partition needed for the current record exists
        PERFORM 1
        FROM   pg_catalog.pg_class c
        JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
        WHERE  c.relkind = 'r'
        AND    c.relname = _tablename
        AND    n.nspname = 'public';

        -- If the partition needed does not yet exist, then we create it:
        -- Note that || is string concatenation (joining two strings to make one)
        IF NOT FOUND THEN
            EXECUTE '
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "'||quote_ident(_tablename)||'" ( LIKE "example_table" INCLUDING ALL ) 
                    INHERITS ("example_table");

                ALTER TABLE         "'||quote_ident(_tablename)||'"
                    ADD FOREIGN KEY ("log_id")                          REFERENCES "foreign_example1" ("log_id")                                                            ON DELETE SET NULL,
                    ADD FOREIGN KEY ("detail_log_id")                   REFERENCES "foreign_example2" ("log_id")                                                            ON DELETE SET NULL,
                    ADD FOREIGN KEY ("image_id")                        REFERENCES "foreign_example3" ("image_id")                                                  ON DELETE SET NULL,
                    ADD CONSTRAINT date_check CHECK ("insert_date" >= timestamptz '||quote_literal(_start_date)||' and "insert_date" <= timestamptz '||quote_literal(_end_date)||');

                CREATE TRIGGER "'||quote_ident(_tablename)||'_create_alarm" AFTER INSERT ON "'||quote_ident(_tablename)||'"
                FOR EACH ROW
                EXECUTE PROCEDURE "public"."external_trigger_example"();
            ';
        END IF;
        --
        -- Insert the current record into the correct partition, which we are sure will now exist.
        EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO public.' || quote_ident(_tablename) || ' VALUES ($1.*)' USING NEW;

        RETURN NULL;
        --RETURN NEW;
    END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
```

This Trigger actually works as expected, but this part is a problem:

```
RETURN NULL;
--RETURN NEW;
```

Whatever I return here, is written to the Table - Together with the written content from the contained INSERT Query!
So If I would `RETURN NEW` - I would write duplicates

This is no problem as long as I keep `RETURN NULL` - But when doing so, I Am unable to do any `INSERT RETURNING` Queries (As nothing is returned of course)

So my Question is:
How Could I return the just inserted ID - without creating Duplicates?
Or how could I write this trigger, to return something - but not to actually insert it (only use the contained INSERT from the Trigger)?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Not directly related to your current problem, but you should seriously consider migrating to Postgres 12 (if not already done) and use declarative partitioning, rather than the old (and discouraged now) inheritance based partitioning. You might also want to consider a tool like [pgpartman](https://github.com/pgpartman/pg_partman) which has solved your problems already.

Comment: You cannot - you won't be able to make `INSERT ... RETURNING` work if you don't actually insert anything in the table. Sorry.